# Maven build for surefire-plugin 2.22.2

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, junit

Hello  i'm using apache maven and junit 5.6.2 an d i have this error:
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-cli) on project optimus: No tests were executed!

(Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.) -> [Help 1](http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException)
To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles: [Help 1](http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException)

When i try to clean and build, i have no problem but only when i run the test.

Comment: Do you have a reference to a github project? Please post the pom file and how your Test looks like? My assumption is that you have not added the correct dependencies to your build...but I can only guess ...not enough information here...

Comment: Do you have a multi module project? Give us some more details.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solve, i change my version of maven  to 2.5.2

Comment: What have you change to 2.5.2 ? Maven does not exist in a version 2.5.2?